# How to autoscale plot so axis are not cut off?

Tags: r, plotly

What is the R equivalent of Python's matplotlib's: plt.tight_layout() function. I keep plotting bar graphs in plotly and the axis labels are constantly cut out. And I want to scale the graphs to match.

N.B I am dynamically producing these graphs with different labels, so can't constantly play with margins to get it to fit.

Below is some fake data that will hopefully illustrate the problem

```
Organisation<-c("Organisation Alpha","Organisation Beta","Organisation Charlie","Organisation Delta")
Year<-c(2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019)
Values<-c(100,50,10,0,20,0,75,70)

Mock_data <- data.frame(Organisation, Year, Values, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

p<-Mock_data %>% plot_ly(x=~Organisation,y=~Values,type='bar',frame=~Year,colors="Blues")
```

Comment: Edited to include example

Answer (score 1):

Think I have managed to resolve the issue:

layout(barmode = 'stack',autosize=F,yaxis=list(title=Title,automargin=TRUE),xaxis=list(automargin=T))